# NHibernate, ActiveRecord, Transaction database locks and when Commits are flushed

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, nhprof

This is a common question, but the explanations found so far and observed behaviour are some way apart.

We have want the following nHibernate strategy in our MVC website:

- A `SessionScope` for the request (to track changes)
- An `ActiveRecord.TransactonScope` to wrap our inserts only (to enable rollback/commit of batch)
- Selects to be outside a Transaction (to reduce extent of locks)
- Delayed Flush of inserts (so that our insert/updates occur as a UoW at end of session)

Now currently we:

- Don't get the implied transaction from the `SessionScope` (with FlushAction Auto or Never)
- If we use `ActiveRecord.TransactionScope` there is no delayed flush and any contained selects are also caught up in a long-running transaction.

I'm wondering if it's because we have an old version of nHibernate (it was from trunk very near 2.0).

We just can't get the expected nHibernate behaviour, and performance sucks (using NHProf and SqlProfiler to monitor db locks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what we have tried since:

- Written our own TransactionScope (inherits from ITransactionScope) that:

  - Opens a `ActiveRecord.TransactionScope` on the **Commit**, not in the `ctor` (delays transaction until needed)
  - Opens a 'SessionScope' in the `ctor` if none are available (as a guard)
- Converted our ids to Guid from identity

  - This stopped the auto flush of `insert`/`update` outside of the Transaction (!)

Now we have the following application behaviour:

- Request from MVC

  - `SELECT`s needed by services are fired, all outside a transaction
  - `Repository.Add` calls do not hit the db until `scope.Commit` is called in our Controllers
  - All `INSERT`s / `UPDATE`s occur wrapped inside a transaction as an atomic unit, with no `SELECT`s contained.

... But for some reason nHProf now != sqlProfiler (`select`s seems to happen in the db before nHProf reports it).

**NOTE**
Before I get flamed I realise the issues here, and know that the SELECTs aren't in the Transaction. That's the design. Some of our operations will contain the SELECTs (we now have a couple of our own `TransactionScope` implementations) in serialised transactions. The vast majority of our code does not need up-to-the-minute live data, and we have serialised workloads with individual operators.

**ALSO**
If anyone knows how to get an identity column (non-PK) refreshed post-`insert` without a need to manually refresh the entity, and in particular by using ActiveRecord markup (I think it's possible in nHibernate mapping files using a 'generated' attribute) **please** let me know!!

Comment: We also implemented a custom addition to ActiveRecord to allow the NH property 'generateinserts' to be specified.